# how to get the current location position in map on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

i am creating an application in which i want to get the current location of the user where he is and display it on the map and when the user reaches the destination location from current location the destination location should also be pointed in the map along the direction of travel.
In my xib i have added a button & on action(showDirectionsToHere) of button i have called map 
I have added the following code in my appdelegate but it gives me an error:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    printf("\n Latitude = " "\n Longitude = " " ",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc]init]autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    //[self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    printf("\nerror");
}
- (IBAction)showDirectionsToHere {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [self getCurrentLocation];  // LINE 1

    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=old\%20Location&daddr=%f,%f", newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude];//Line 2
}
```

in line 1 of action(showDirectionsHere) i get error of invalid initializer
in Line 2 i get error that newLocation undeclared.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the code for `getCurrentLocation` so that we can see what it returns.
The variable `newLocation` is undeclared. I think you meant `currentLocation` in the function.

Comment: IBAction)showDirectionsToHere {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [self getCurrentLocation];  // LINE 1

    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=old\%20Location&daddr=%f,%f", newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude];//Line 2
}   getcurrentlocation returns LocationManager object

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [self getCurrentLocation]; means getCurrentLocation returns an object of type CLLocationCoordinate2D which is stored in currentLocation. modify your class to get the location correctly

Comment: how to convert it please help me

Comment: Make an instance variable and set the current location in the didUpdateLocation Then this variable can be returned in [self getCurrentLocation];

Comment: what should be the type of instance variable

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D would be fine I think. But choose according to ur needs

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=old\%20Location&daddr=%f,%f", currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude];
```